# Is it a good practice to move all the commonly used global variables to one header file to reduce the number of #includes?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have couple of global static variables and some basic classes in one project.
Because they are very frequently used, sometimes, I have to include the whole header file just to gain access to those global variables and classes.
Is it a good practice to move all those variables and classes to one single file?

Comment: I don't see why not, at least you are minimizing the damage.

Comment: @yngum , in every separate files, it is easy to categorize them, but moving them to one single file for convenience seem to break the tidiness of the categorization.

Comment: you can categorize them by putting them into a giant class call `global`.

Comment: @yngum, that is definitely a good idea, however, one possible consequence may be that categorization then is no longer mutually exclusive.

Comment: You should also consider the build dependencies.  If the header file changes, all files that include the header file will be rebuilt.  May not be an issue for small projects, but small projects may grow into huge projects.

Comment: Given that there exist well-designed projects with more than one header, and not grouped by frequency of use, clearly it's *sometimes* a good idea to separate even commonly-used things into different headers. Since there exist well-designed projects with more things than headers, clearly it's *sometimes* a good idea to put multiple things in one header. I don't think there's sufficient information in the question to answer it. We can't approve or disapprove of your headers without knowing anything about them other than that they contain objects and classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a rather difficult question to answer.  In general it's a good practice not to use global variables, but it's not always practical.  It really comes down to a question of design.  Header files should encompass a specific set of functionality (like a class).  Globals that are associated with specific functionality should be in the header that most reflects that functionality.  Sometimes you end up with things that don't really fit anywhere (perhaps due to a design problem).  In that case you can gather things into a single header.  When you do consider commenting the globals and your reasoning for structuring things in this manner.

Comment: Reminder:  declare the *global* variables as `extern` in the header files or each source file that includes the header file will generate a new, duplicate, copy of the global variable.  Another reason to stay away from them.